# How to run query on with in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am wondering how possible this is. I have this code below and want to get the avg of rating in the ratings table loaded with 'with'.

```php
$this['ads'] = Advert::with('ratings')
    ->whereHas('cats', function ($query) use ($slug) {
        $query->where('slug', $slug);
    })
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

How can i do this?
Tried this but not working

```php
$this['ads'] = Advert
    ::with(['ratings' => function ($query) {
        $query->avg('rating');
    }])
    ->whereHas('cats', function ($query) use ($slug) {
        $query->where('slug', $slug);
    })
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

No Error, it just displays the rated numbers as before

I am using twig to output the result

```
{% for star in ad.ratings %}

    <p style="font-size: 15px">{{ star.rating }}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

It just displays the ratings as 4 5 2 1 4 instead of the average

Comment: `$this` is a reserved variable for the class scope, I would change your array variable name to something else. If you're trying to access a property, its `$this->ads = Advert::with()...`

Comment: Please can you explain what you mean by "not working" i.e. are you getting an error, are you getting a value that you consider to be wrong, are you not getting an value(s) at all etc.?

Comment: @Rwd Updated my question. Please check

Comment: For aggregated resuts such as average you need to use `group by`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get what you're after is to use `withCount` (instead of `with`) as this method is already set up to retrieve an aggregate value. All you need to do is modify the output slightly:

```
::withCount(['ratings as rating' => function ($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw('avg(rating)'));
}])
```

Then in your `twig` file you can remove the `for` loop and just have:

```
<p style="font-size: 15px">{{ ad.rating }}</p>
```

---

Please note:

- You won't be able to use `$query->avg('rating')` as this won't return the the `advert_id` which Eloquent will need to relate the value back to the correct model.
- Using `$query->selectRaw(...)` instead of `$query->select(DB::raw(...))` won't work either.

---

The whole Eloquent call just for reference:

```php
Advert
    ::withCount(['ratings as rating' => function ($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw('avg(rating)'));
    }])
    ->whereHas('cats', function ($query) use ($slug) {
        $query->where('slug', $slug);
    })
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. But one small thing. Those that have not been rated displays ''0''. Is there a way to abstract that away?

Comment: @OsujiKingsley As in don't show the rating or don't show the `Advert` at all?

Comment: The average works and displays as 4.5, 2.3, for adverts that have been rated but adverts that have not been rated displays 0 instead of showing nothing. But i well decided to just use font awesome stars to show the avg ratings.

Comment: @OsujiKingsley That'll be because the raw query was using `COALESCE`, I've updated my answer to remove it.